# Where is a list of I/O ports used in real-mode code?

Tags: assembly, real-mode

I am looking at some existing real-mode code that uses the in and out assembly instruction.

I recognize a few, but I don't know what most of the different ports in the instructions are related to.

Is there a list of what the different I/O ports refer to?

Comment: since ports "interfaces" the cpu to extern peripheric "circuit", you have to know which is your architecture. Likely it is the "standard" intel arch we can see on modern desktop computers; but anyway it is worth knowing what in/out do depends heavily on the specifi hardware, not only on the cpu alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/Output_Base_Address), for x86.